# How do I copy only certain parts of a DVD and burn them to a different DVD?

Tags: dvd, burning, ripping

I have DVDs (movies and TV shows, that is) that I would like to backup for my own use but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I've been using DVD Decrypter to get the files from the DVDs but my problem is that I only want the main DVD content, not special features, etc. I can rip an ISO, compress it with something like DVD Shrink and then burn it to a DVD but that includes all of the extra stuff I don't want. Is there a way to burn just the VOB and IFO files that I want back to a DVD in such a way that the disc will play on a regular DVD player?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: So there's no way to simply burn the VOB files onto a blank DVD and have the disc work in DVD players? I have to use DVD re-authoring software? In other words, I can't just burn the proper files and have it work, right?

Answer (score 1):

DVD Shrink can do this if you use the "Re-author" mode. No need to rip it first - just go to "open disc", then click on "Re-author". From there you can add the titles you want, as well as removing unnecessary audio tracks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DVD authoring software, which will allow you to remove the menus, only burn the portions you want, and even burn multiple titles to the same disc if you have room.

I use [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.de/), a free program available for Windows, Mac, and Linux.  There are also many commercial packages available.

Answer (score 0):

As far as extraction is concerned, I'm not sure what to recommend (hopefully someone else can help you with that part of the answer), but there's an excellent free/open-source program called DVD Flick that I've used a few times to create a DVD that's playable in regular DVD players:

DVD Flick
  http://www.dvdflick.net/

It includes a customizable menu system which allows you to select which frame in the video to use for the preview image (the default it picks is usually pretty go though anyway), and it's really good at mixing various audio and video formats together.

You'll get a .ISO file that you can then burn to your 4 GB or 8 GB writable DVD.

Answer (score 0):

As **user55325** said, DVDShrink (in reauthor mode) is great; it’s my favorite and first choice. However, you should be aware that because it is fairly old and no longer update or supported, it will have trouble with some discs (eg ones with structural copy protection, multi-angle titles, “photo-slideshow” titles, etc.)

In general you will want to use Shrink for general purpose use, but sometimes you’ll also need to rip the disc to the hard-drive first, then open the ripped files in Shrink. Two frequently used (and not free, but regularly updated) apps for this purpose are Slysoft’s AnyDVD and DVDFab’s HD-Decryptor.

There’s [some guides](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/DVD_Shrink#guides) available on using DVD Shrink to accomplish all kinds of basic through advanced things; particularly check out the guides on re-authoring.